# iphone - Scan complete Image for pixel color

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have following question: How can I scan a complete image to get for every pixel it's color.

I use this library https://github.com/unixpickle/ANImageBitmapRep.

I have this code:

```
- (void)executeImageScanProcessWithImage:(UIImage *)image{


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {


    NSString *rowString = @"";
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ANImageBitmapRep *imageBitmap;
    UIColor *color;
    // Loop für die Spalten (y)
    for (int y = 0; y < 320; y += 20) {
        rowString = @""; // rowString zurücksetzen

        // Loop für die Reihe (x)
        for (int x = 0; x < image.size.width; x += 20) {

            BMPoint pixelPoint = BMPointMake(x, y);
            imageBitmap = [ANImageBitmapRep imageBitmapRepWithImage:image];
            BMPixel pixel = [imageBitmap getPixelAtPoint:pixelPoint];
            color = UIColorFromBMPixel(pixel);

            if ([color isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]) {
                rowString = [rowString stringByAppendingFormat:@"0"];
            }
            else {
                rowString = [rowString stringByAppendingFormat:@"1"];
            }

            // Wenn der letzte "Run" vollzogen ist, wird die rowString in den Array hinzugefügt
            if ([rowString length] == image.size.width / 20) {
                [array addObject:rowString];
            }
        }

        [array addObject:rowString];
    }

    NSLog(@"content of array = %@",array);


});
```

}

The Problem is that I get this error, when the image gets too big.

> Malloc failed which is too bad.  I was hoping to use this memory. Jul
>   24 18:31:41 Christians-MacBook-Pro.local Bitmap_Test[2374] :
>   CGBitmapContextGetData: invalid context 0x0 Jul 24 18:31:41
>   Christians-MacBook-Pro.local Bitmap_Test[2374] :
>   CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0 Jul 24 18:31:41
>   Christians-MacBook-Pro.local Bitmap_Test[2374] :
>   CGBitmapContextGetWidth: invalid context 0x0
>   Bitmap_Test(2374,0xb0103000) malloc: *** mmap(size=2265088) failed
>   (error code=12)

Do you know another approach to deal with this plan?

Best regards from Germany,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another thread's code, which i replaced with my code.

Here is the thread:
[How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)